# Different credentials in Azure publish profile

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-configuration

Let's say I just want to upload a simple index.html file on my Azure web site (called "test").
To do this, I set my deployment credentials.
For example, username: frog
             password: froggy

I am able to use these credentials to upload the file using an FTP client (i.e. FileZilla) but when I download the PublishProfile it has different credentials.
Namely, username: test\$test
        password: (someEncryptedLongCharacters)

These last credentials work as well!

What is going on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every site has two types of FTP credentials: The credentials for the admin user of the site (which is what you're expecting), and the site's own FTP credentials. When you download the publishing profile you're seeing the site's own credentials.

Comment: Thx for the clarification. But should both of them work? If I have the site's credentials then why do I need admin's credentials? What is he difference?
I am a noob in web development so be understanding! Thx again

Comment: @padawanTony You'll normally use the admin credentials when you log in to your websites, since the same admin creds will get you into all the sites that you own.  The website creds are usually used by tools like Visual Studio to manage your site. The tools get your site's site credentials via the Publishing Profile xml file.  Every site has it's own site credential in order to let you only grant access to the sites you want those tools to be able to access.  In that context, your admin cred is kind of like the god credential